# How to store a table with varying number of columns and rows? C++

Tags: c++, database, sorting

I'm very confused with the new programming assignment we got in class a few days ago. It asks us to read info from a file which contains an unknown number of rows and columns and then sort the data. My question is how do I do that?

My reasoning was that if I knew the number of columns, I would just create an array of structures and then create a new structure for each row. But since the number of columns is also unknown, I don't know how to approach this.

Also, we only allowed to use `<iostream>` `<fstream>`, `<cctype>` and `<vector>` libraries.

Comment: what have you tried?  post some sample code of what you have so far.  Also correct the sentence `Also, we only allowed to use , and libraries.` as it is unclear as to what you are trying to say or what the restriction actually is.

Comment: If you are to "sort the data", what kind of sort are you planning ... numbers of each line, but then how sort the lines?  Maybe all the numbers in all lines go into single vector - a simple sort, but increasing? decreasing?  And the column idea is to simply to confuse you (and us)?  Perhaps he is asking you to define your interpretation of the problem (then do it), or wanting you to contact him/her (or his TA) for the information you need to complete the assignment.

Comment: i'm sorry. I tried to list the libraries between the less than and greater than symbols, but apparently they are not allowed. What I was trying to say is that we can only use iostream, fstream, vector and cctype. As for sorting, I simply need to sort it in increasing/decreasing order. The data in the table will be of types int, double and string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a

```
std::vector<std::vector<WhateverTypeYouWantToStore>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use std::vector. You can create a 2D vector like this:

```
vector<vector<string> > table;
```

And then read the lines from a file, and put the data into a one dimensional vector (`vector<string> line`). And then, You can push_back the line vector into the table, like this:

```
table.push_back(line);
```

You can see more information about vector on this page: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must know what format of data that you are going to read from text file's row and column. First to understand, you will read first row, then second row and so on. If you do not know type of data, then believe all of it as string of characters. So, you can assume wherever you fine null char '\0' then you are finding data for first row, so go on read character by character look for next '\0'. Then wherever you find '\n' that will be last point of first row and you just discovered last column. After '\n' you will start reading 2nd row and so on. With this you can determine how many rows and columns are there. You keep on reading text file until you reach EOF.
See the attached image. 
[Text File Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oSpg.png)
Also, define a pointer to character type and use realloc to assign memory to it. With realloc() you can grow it, as you find more data. Please go through realloc() manual for reference.